# Can we taste electrons?

Tags: sensation, electrical-stimulation, peripheral-nervous-system, sensory-systems, taste

Why does licking a 9-Volt battery elicits a taste sensation? Can taste be stimulated by electrical stimulation?

Comment: I'm assuming stimulating a taste receptor generates a "taste", and there are no taste receptors on your knee. This could be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_lollipop

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Short answer**
*Yes*, taste sensations can be generated electrically. However, we cannot taste electrons themselves, as taste-receptor proteins on the taste receptor cells are not activated by electrons. Instead, electrical currents stimulate taste receptors *directly* by depolarizing the cell membrane, without the need of activation of the proteins that normally bind ions or molecules.

**Background**
There is a medical device called the **[BrainPort](http://www.wicab.com/#!brainport-v100/ee7ds)** that electrically stimulates the tongue (Fig. 1.) The device is marketed as an electrotactile vision substitution device. Basically, it captures images of the outside world with a glasses-mounted camera and these images are translated into electrical stimuli presented on a 20 x 20 electrode array. That array is embedded in the tongue display unit (aka intra-oral device, IOD). The IOD is worn on the tongue.

[image: BrainPort V100]
<sup>Fig. 1. BrainPort V100. source: [TuWindowsMundo](http://www.tuwindowsmundo.com/brainport-permitira-ver-a-estadounidenses-ciegos/)</sup>

It typically generates electrotactile sensations, like [champagne bubbles](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/62220/20150621/fda-approves-brainport-v100-a-gadget-that-allegedly-help-blind-people-see-with-their-tongues.htm). However, some subjects do report [metallic **taste** sensations](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/62220/20150621/fda-approves-brainport-v100-a-gadget-that-allegedly-help-blind-people-see-with-their-tongues.htm) when using the device. In fact, [Lawless *et al.* (2005)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1307523/)* investigated the electrically evoked metallic-taste in response to anodic stimulation of the tongue directly and confirmed the anecdotal reports obtained with the BrainpPort device that electric stimuli evoke metallic-taste sensations.

Physiologically, taste receptor cells sense certain compounds (salts, acids etc.) due to activation of receptor molecules on the cell's surface. In turn, activation of receptor molecules depolarizes the cell membrane which eventually lead to neurotransmitter release and activation of secondary neurons that transmit the signal up to the brain (Fig. 2). Electrical stimuli **bypass** the receptor molecules and *directly depolarize the taste receptor cells*.

Given the anatomy of the taste receptor system in the tongue (Fig. 2), I am inclined to believe that the taste receptors are stimulated directly, and not the secondary neurons, because they are situated in deeper layers.

[image: Neural gustatory receptor pathway]
<sup>Fig. 2. Neural pathway of the taste buds on the tongue. Note that the secondary neurons transporting the taste information to the brain are situated in deeper layers than the taste buds. Source: [Universe Review](https://universe-review.ca/R10-16-ANS06.htm).</sup>

Note that [taste receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste_receptor) do *not* sense electrons. Rather, larger ions or molecules may stimulate them and cause a [**depolarization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste_receptor) of the receptor cell, in turn activating the secondary neuron via a chemical synapse.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Lawless *et al*., *Chem Senses* (2005); **30**(3): 185–94](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1307523/)</sub>

<sub>**Acknowledgment**

*Credits for the [Lawless *et al*. (2005)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1307523/) reference go to @CMK</sub>

Comment: I have also heard of some device that can produce tastes of different foods via electrical stimulation. I am not sure if this is the same device.